# How to show a long length string that is taken from a TextField(material-ui)?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, tooltip, textfield, card

I hope you are doing fine! I do not want to waste your time, however I am searching for hours and I cannot find anything to help me proceed with my problem.

I am trying to figure out if there is a way for me to show the string inside of multiple **Cards** with the help of a **Tooltip**. Imagine that you have 2 **PostCards** with some text inside them, but the properties of the **TextField** are setted like that so that the big sized strings are not fully showed i.e. **"This is a long...."** which essentially is **"This is a long string and cannot fit"**. I would like to show on hovering the full text, something similar to when you use the **Tooltip** of **Material-ui**. Is there any way for me to do it without using custom css properties?

Thank you for your time and I ask for your forgiveness in case this is already answered somewhere and I could not find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you'd use CSS to control the formatting to accomplish this behavior.  I created a simple example using a `span` (needs to use `display: inline-block;` to work), but will work with other tags too.

I'm also using jQuery to inject the same text in to the span, and also the `title` attribute. You don't have to use it, but it makes this example much easier.

You may be able to trim it with javascript before displaying it, but that may be too much work to trim it to the correct width of the target element.  With CSS it will fit the text to the specified width. If you don't want to use CSS, then at least this gives you an example of how CSS would work.

```js
var sampleText = "This is an example of some long text";

$(".sample").attr("title", sampleText).text(sampleText);
```

```css
.sample {
  display: inline-block;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  max-width: 60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="sample"></span>
```

To use with react, you can still use CSS, but then just inject the text with:

```html
    <span className={sample} title={sampleText}>{sampleText}</span>
```

Comment: Hello @r-Blue, thank you a lot for your answer and your effort! I cannot run the code snippet for some reason. And to be honest I do not see how I could have a similar animation to the Tooltip of material-ui. My problem is how to apply that sort of animation to long answers. Meaning that in the postcard it shows "This is a long..." but when you hover on the answer there is an animation comes like the tooltip that provides the whole string. Something like this [link](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-tooltip/#variable-width) but I would like to make it for every single PostCard.